# Autoplay video start time same as clock time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 24 hour video that I want it to start at the same time of what time it current is. For example, if it is 06:24:12 a.m, the video will autoplay and start at hour 6 minute 24 12 seconds. Right now it does not seem like it is starting at all.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function checkTimeAndPlay() {
    var date = new Date();
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    vid.currentTime = (date.getHours()*3600) + (date.getMinutes()*60) + date.getSeconds();
    vid.play();
  checkTimeAndPlay();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Clock</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>


 <video id="myVideo" width="640" height="360" controls>
   <source src="assets\video\clockvid.mp4" type="video/mp4">

 </video>


</body>

</html>
```

`

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: @Herohtar my video does not seem to be auto playing at the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a curly bracket there:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function checkTimeAndPlay() {
    var date = new Date();
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    vid.currentTime = (date.getHours()*3600) + (date.getMinutes()*60) + date.getSeconds();
    vid.play();
  } // <= missing
  checkTimeAndPlay();
});
```

It's a good idea to look at the errors in your browser's console or whatever environment you're using to execute code.

Comment: Got it. Many thanks. Do you know why it is not autoplaying? The video seeks to the time but it's not starting if I add controls.

Comment: @Futuretrunks Most browsers now disable autoplay unless the video has no audio or is muted or otherwise has the volume set to 0.

Comment: Oh I did not know that. Many thanks. Everything is working now.